# Custom Alerts Tag Helper not displaying on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, azure

I implemented a custom alert system into my .NET 2.2 application using the following guide: https://www.matheus.ro/2017/12/18/how-to-create-a-simple-alert-system-using-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

This works perfectly when I run it locally, however I deployed to the live server on Azure last night and noticed that **none** of the alerts were appearing.

What could be the reason for this? I am not sure how to effectively debug this issue.

**AlertsTagHelper.cs:**

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("alerts")]
    public class AlertsTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string AlertKey = "SEPMTool.Alert";
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
        protected ITempDataDictionary TempData => ViewContext.TempData;
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "div";
            if (TempData[AlertKey] == null)
                TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HashSet<Alert>());
            var alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Alert>>(TempData[AlertKey].ToString());
            var html = string.Empty;
            foreach (var alert in alerts)
            {
                html += $"<div class='alert {alert.Type}' id='inner-alert' role='alert'>" +
                            $"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>" +
                                $"<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>" +
                            $"</button>" +
                            $"{alert.Message}" +
                        $"</div>";
            }
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(html);
        }
    }
```

**AlertExtensions.cs:**

```
public static class AlertExtensions
    {
        private const string AlertKey = "SEPMTool.Alert";
        public static void AddAlertSuccess(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            var alerts = GetAlerts(controller);
            alerts.Add(new Alert(message, "alert-success"));
            controller.TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts);
        }
        public static void AddAlertInfo(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            var alerts = GetAlerts(controller);
            alerts.Add(new Alert(message, "alert-info"));
            controller.TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts);
        }
        public static void AddAlertWarning(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            var alerts = GetAlerts(controller);
            alerts.Add(new Alert(message, "alert-warning"));
            controller.TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts);
        }
        public static void AddAlertDanger(this Controller controller, string message)
        {
            var alerts = GetAlerts(controller);
            alerts.Add(new Alert(message, "alert-danger"));
            controller.TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts);
        }
        private static ICollection<Alert> GetAlerts(Controller controller)
        {
            if (controller.TempData[AlertKey] == null)
                controller.TempData[AlertKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HashSet<Alert>());
            ICollection<Alert> alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICollection<Alert>>(controller.TempData[AlertKey].ToString());
            if (alerts == null)
            {
                alerts = new HashSet<Alert>();
            }
            return alerts;
        }
    }
```

**Alert.cs:**

```
public class Alert
    {
        public string Message;
        public string Type;

        public Alert(string message, string type)
        {
            Message = message;
            Type = type;
        }
    }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@inject IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="A Software Engineering Project Management Tool by Ben Hayward">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/assets/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/dist/assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout layout-nav-side">
        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
        <div class="main-container">
            <div id="mainContent" v-cloak>
                <partial name="_BreadcrumbBarPartial" />
                <alerts></alerts>
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/autosize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/prism.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/draggable.bundle.legacy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/swap-animation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/list.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Required theme scripts (Do not remove) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/assets/js/theme.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/build/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: "#mainContent",
        mixins: vueMixins
    });
    @if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        @:Vue.config.devtools = true;
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml:**

```
@using SEPMTool
@using SEPMTool.Models
@addTagHelper *, SEPMTool
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper "*, cloudscribe.Web.Pagination"
```

**Alert Trigger in Controller:**

```
            if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
            {
                this.AddAlertSuccess($"{projectTask.TaskName} was created successfully");
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = projectTask.ProjectId });
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on browser console?

Comment: how you trigger this alert?

Comment: @PankajRawat Sorry I forgot to include how the alert is triggered, I have now edited the post with the trigger at the bottom.

Also, I am getting no error on the browser

Comment: The application is deployed on a single app service or multiple (customer of VMS)?

Comment: It's deployed on a single Azure app service

Comment: Application should work on a single server, I see an issue when application deployed on multiple server

Comment: @PankajRawat I am fairly certain it's only deployed on a single server. But what is the issue when the application is deployed on multiple servers, maybe I can try that?

Comment: @PankajRawat https://imgur.com/a/Z37UF3V

Comment: Try remote debugging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio

Comment: @PankajRawat I'll give this a try now, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211219/discussion-between-benhayward-and-pankaj-rawat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue, it was caused by the consent cookie being required, with no capability for anyone to accept it.

Credit to: @Smurtagh

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When application deploys on multiple servers, In that case, application may not display message all the time. Above code use tempData

> The TempData uses a session variable internally to store data between requests. And Session data will store on a single server. Then you have to make sure one user all request should go on same server. Check your Session affinity / ARR affinity setting in Azure App Service level or Load balancer level.

Comment: ARR affinity was set to 'on', I set it to 'off' and restarted the app, unfortunately, the problem still persists.